# Not able to generate tables from Jooq Jooq Configuration jooq.properties for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, configuration, jooq

I have generated the java model files from MySQL tables. But now we are switching to PostgreSQL and i need everything to work there. So i have created a new jooq.properties files for PostgreSQL configuration. However it does not generate any model files from the table.

The jooq.properties file for PostgreSQL is

```
#Configure the database connection here
jdbc.Driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/ofbiz_olo
jdbc.Schema=public
jdbc.User=postgres
jdbc.Password=standard

#The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style
generator=org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator

#The database type. The format here is:
#generator.database=org.util.[database].[database]Database
generator.database=org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase

#All elements that are generated from your schema (several Java regular expressions, separated by comma)
generator.database.includes=OLO.*,USER_LOGIN,PRODUCT,PERSON

#All elements that are excluded from your schema (several Java regular expressions, separated by comma). Excludes match before includes
generator.database.excludes=

#Primary key / foreign key relations should be generated and used. 
#This will be a prerequisite for various advanced features
generator.generate.relations=true

#The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory)
generator.target.package=com.olo.base.model

#The destination directory of your generated classes
generator.target.directory=src
```

The output that i get in commandline is

```
INFO: Initialising properties  : /jooq.properties
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Database parameters      
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO:   dialect                : POSTGRES
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO:   schema                 : public
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO:   target dir             : src
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO:   target package         : com.olo.base.model
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Emptying                 : /home/shekhar/Projects/olo_sf_base/src/com/olo/base/model
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating classes in    : /home/shekhar/Projects/olo_sf_base/src/com/olo/base/model
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating schema        : Public.java
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Generating factory       : PublicFactory.java
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Schema generated         : Total: 67.978ms
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Sequences fetched        : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Masterdata tables fetched: 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Tables fetched           : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: UDTs fetched             : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: ARRAYs fetched           : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:11 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Enums fetched            : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Procedures fetched       : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Functions fetched        : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: Packages fetched         : 0
14 Jul, 2011 8:41:12 PM org.jooq.impl.JooqLogger info
INFO: GENERATION FINISHED!     : Total: 728.67ms, +660.692ms
```

PostgreSQL information in pgAdmin3 looks like pgsql->databases->ofbiz_olo->Schemas->public->Tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Historic answer for jOOQ 1.x:

Maybe, try (lower-case letters)

```
generator.database.includes=olo.*,user_login,product,person
```

Or even

```
generator.database.includes=.*
```

Comment: thanks lukas! i was stuck for more than 2 hours on this since the same (without lowercase) is working fine on MySQL.

Comment: Yes, the regular expression is case-sensitive because some databases are case-sensitive, also... This should be documented in the manual...

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped me as well!